# IISExpress to use new dotnet run instead of dnx web

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have upgraded to the latest rc2-16551 release, and lets face it, its completely broken!  I know, this is what you get for using pre-release stuff, anyway.

It seems that now there is the new dotnet-cli released and instead of using commands like `dun restore` or `dnx web` we are supposed to use `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` (If i am wrong, please let me know, as this is just what i am presuming, after what i have read)

Now how can i get my IISExpress to run the `dotnet run` command instead of `dnx web`??

Is this possible?

Comment: If I am not mistaken in rc2 there is the whole dotnet component that will need to be used that wasn't used before. I haven't used rc2 because the only people I have seen use rc2 is the Microsoft team and even they say it's not ready yet. I am waiting for the guide to come out before I do anything with it...

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.NET Core is running under IIS and IISExpress Requests are sent to the kestrel http server via a http handler that is set up by the web.config file that sits in the route of the wwwroot folder.

The key line in that file is

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
```

I guess you could alter this to point at whatever thing that replaces DNX in RC2. Sadly I haven't played with it yet so don't know much about it.

Comment: The question was about IIS express wasn't it ?

Comment: Yep... IIS Express works the same as far as I can tell.